# Writing a PowerShell Script To Copy Directories Every Week

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api

I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me out.  I want to copy a directory located on two different network drives to my computer for DR.  I know I can use Copy-Item, but I was wondering if anyone had a better way I can write it outside of doing:

```
Copy-Item '\\blah\blah\blah' -Destination 'C:\DR' -Recurse -Container
```

Also I am not sure but is there a way for me to copy out a file from Google Drive in PowerShell?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?  How about calling robocopy from your script instead of using copy-item?  As for your Google Drive question, Google provides some .net assemblies in the Drive SDK, so it shouldn't be too hard to write a PowerShell cmdlet that uses them to download a file.

Comment: I was not sure if there was another way not another way of writing it code.  I mean seeing @Rahul Answer I could use variables, but for what ever reason I though I could write the copy and schedule the task to over write the past files (which now looking at it I am having issues with the overwriting) all at the same time in PowerShell.  As for the Google part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with `copy-item` commandlet which can help you copy entire directory recursively
like

```
$from = "<mypath>\<mydirectory>\*"
$to = "\\<different_machine_name>\<some_destination_folder>\"
Copy-Item $from $to -recurse
```

About Google drive access, I believe you can access google drive using explorer like any other folder. So, it should be accessible using powershell as well.

Found this link, might be of help.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/6tcDlfMMoIw

Answer (score 2):

The Copy-Item cmdlet is the cmdlet you would want to use for copying items between directories. Remote or otherwise. You would just need to use the UNC path or the path you have mapped on your computer.

As for copying files from Google Drive if you have the desktop application installed then you wouldn't have to do anything fancy. It automatically syncs the files in your gDrive to a folder on the local machine.

Otherwise you would need to utilize the Google Drive API in order to get the files from your Google Drive. This is also possible using Powershell.

http://www.rssbus.com/kb/articles/ado-googlepowershell.rst